# Can dwarves and elves produce offspring (between each other)?

Tags: the-lord-of-the-rings, tolkiens-legendarium, canon

Given the changes in the new Hobbit movies, I was just wondering if a dwarf and an elf could produce offspring in Tolkien canon?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Tauriel's story arc - spoiler alert (movie only)](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/46341/tauriels-story-arc-spoiler-alert-movie-only)

Comment: Elves and humans can interbreed, but they were both created by Eru. Dwarves were not, so it's possible (likely?) that they can't.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because:
1. Clearly doesn't appear to be in good faith
2. It's one google search away that humans are an entirely different race and not hybrids.

Comment: @JohnO - good faith is irrelevant. It's a good question regardless of whether it was asked out of genuine thirst for biological knowledge or just to be a smart-alec. I edited out the smartalec parts anyway.

Comment: Sorry, it's not irrelevant. Questions asked in bad faith can't have good answers, and this site isn't designed for people to do PR for science fiction by trying to come up with good answers to bad questions.

Comment: @JohnO The second part was clearly a joke. I am legitimately interested in if dwarves and elves can produce offspring together in the Tolkien universe.

Comment: I think DNA compatibility are the least of the concerns with regard to Legolas and Gimli producing a child...

Comment: The movies, to my understanding, aren't considered Tolkien canon- especially given that he's dead.

Comment: Speculative, unrealized question of canon.  Can an Orc and Hobbit reproduce simply because Tolkein [long-dead] didn't say otherwise?

Answer (score 1):

There is no definitive answer in cannon but I think it is assumed that because elves and men all come from the same ancestors and then branched off they are still compatible whereas dwarves are a completely different lifeform. It's like the animal kingdom- men and elves are different species but in the same family; Dwarves, however, are an entirely different phylum. Peter Jackson is simplu taking verifiable fact and making it fantasy (sarcasm)!

Comment: `because elves and men all come from the same ancestors`- that's not true. They were created by the same being (Eru), but they did NOT have common ancestors.