# Tolkien: Is there any incidence of a romance between a dwarf and a man/woman?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, elves, dwarves, love

Following up this question about love between Dwarfs and Elves ([What inspired Tauriel's story arc?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/46341/what-inspired-tauriels-story-arc)), I wondered whether there is any incidence of a romance between a dwarf and a man/woman? The question of possible reproduction is not at the center of my question; it is more about falling in love. My own hypotheses are twofold:

- just as for the case Elves/dwarfs: While man was created by Ilúvatar, dwarfs were created by Aulë. That would speak against them having a romantic relationship.
- Men and dwarfs are both bound to die eventually, making them different from elves.

Please note that this question is not about whether the relationship should be male man -- female dwarf // male-man -- male dwarf // female human -- male dwarf // female human -- female dwarf. However, if there actually IS any difference between those, I'm glad to hear!

Comment: The first line of the first answer explicitly answers this question.

Comment: @Richard: I only see that answer addressing relationships between dwarves and elves, not between dwarves and men.

Comment: @NateEldredge - Actually you're right. I've edited the top-voted answer to include a line relating to Dwarf/Human (ahem) *relations*

Comment: awesome! Thanks for the edit! So in that case, Richard, the argumentation about their different orginis is stronger than the fact that both species are bound to die, correct!?